# Powershell DownloadFile(,) command giving 403 - Forbidden error

Tags: powershell, download

I am using Powershell `DownloadFile(,)` command for reading a .csv file from a document library in SharePoint 2013 site. When i ran the code on my DEV environment, it ran properly. The DEV environment is using `http://`. But , when I run this code on TEST environment i get `403 Forbidden` error. The site(TEST environment) is running over `https://`.

I am using below code ,

```
$FilePath = "https://ServerName/sites/SiteName/MyDocumentLibrary/MyCSVFile.csv"
$localPath = "C:\temp\test.csv" 
$wc = New-Object System.Net.Webclient
$wc.DownloadFile($FilePath, $localPath)
$list = Import-Csv $localPath
```

The error says,

> Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote
>   server returned an error: (403) Forbidden." At
>   D:\Amit\UpdateUserInformationList.ps1:39 char:1

I have gone through various articles which talks about passing credentials with the `Webclient($wc)` object. But, with no luck. Still getting same error.

I am still unaware, when/why does Powershell throws this error ? What is the root cause of this error?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `UserAgent` as part of `$wc`?

Comment: I don't think so...can you provide an sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long day, it turned out that for successfully using the Powershell `DownloadFile()` method, in my environment (SP2013 with ADFS) following two lines did the trick(at least for me).

```
$wc.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$wc.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f")
```

So, the final code looks like,

```
$FilePath = "https://ServerName/sites/SiteName/MyDocumentLibrary/MyCSVFile.csv"
$localPath = "C:\temp\test.csv" #Make sure the folder do exist
$wc = New-Object System.Net.Webclient
$wc.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$wc.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f")
$wc.DownloadFile($FilePath, $localPath)
$list = Import-Csv $localPath
```

I got help from the last comment(which is not marked as answer for that question :-)) of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866958/downloading-a-file-from-sharepoint-online-with-%20%20powershell) post.

Comment: This will work if you are accessing remote resource from your own credentials.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential(Username, Password, Domain)

$UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)"
$wc.Headers.Add([System.Net.HttpRequestHeader]::UserAgent, $UserAgent);
```

Comment: I am getting a warning `WARNING: One or more headers were not specified. Default names starting with "H" have been used in place of any missing headers.` and the file is created at `C:\temp\test.csv`. But the file contains the HTML of the ADFS provider selection page(login page), instead of the actual content expected.

Comment: @AmitTyagi see my update.. Try passing the credentials also

Comment: No success. Do i need to pass the domain also with the credentials. As i am using ADFS and the credentials i am using are not of AD.

Comment: Thanks Amal, for investing time. I got the solution as mentioned in the answer posted by me.